# Which op amp to use?

Tags: voltage, negative

I am working on a control system project which involves making a transfer function using op amps. The circuit I need to make is the following [image] . **My question is if I can substitute the 4 LM741 op amps with 1 LM324N so that there wont be a need for a negative voltage,right?** I am a bit confused since the professor told us to use the LM741 explicitly but after q quick search the LM324N seemed liked a better choice.

Also could anyone tell me whats the difference between op amps that need negative voltage and those that don't? like the LM324N.

Comment: There is no difference. If the input voltage goes negative you need a negative supply voltage with the 324 too. If you stop the input going negative (by adding V1/2 DC bias to the input) the 741 will work on a single supply too. HOWEVER the741 won't work on as low as 5V while the 324 will (if you don't expect too much from it)

Answer (score 2):

No op-amp needs negative voltage per-se, the op-amp doesn't care what your voltages are relative to some arbitary ground, only what they are relative to each other.

All op-amps require that the range of input and output signal voltages remains within the power rails. Usually they also require some margin between the range of input/output volages and the power supply voltage rails. In some amplifiers these margins are narrower than others and/or asymetric (a smaller margin needed at the negative end than the positive end), such amplifiers are marketed as being suitable for single supply use. The downside of such amplifiers tends to be worse distortion as you get closer to the power rails.

Comment: So If I understand correctly there is no need for negative voltage as a supply to amp if my input is only positive. To be more specific the input is going to be a square pulse, so I will be fine with just positive supply to the amp?

Comment: That depends on your particular amplifier and on how close your input and output signals get to 0V. You typically need some margin between the V- supply to your op-amp and the lowest voltage you will have on the inputs and outputs. How much margin you need depends on the particular op-amp and how much distortion you are prepared to accept.

Answer (score 0):

First the input and output voltage ranges must be within the op amp's power supplies. If the input voltage goes both positive and negative, you op. amp. must have both negative and positive power supplies.

Usually, op. amp. don't have "ground" connections, only V+ and V-. Some are optimised for symmetrical powers, they work best, with minimal distortion in the middle of the range.

Some others, often those compatible with low voltage power supplies (0..5V for example), are best used with positive signals.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I am getting a cleared image now.

Answer (score 0):

You need a negative supply regardless of which op-amp you buy- when the input goes positive the output goes negative for each of the op-amps. The output cannot go more negative than the negative rail, which means the maximum input the above circuit will work with is 0V even with an ideal op-amp.

It's possible by level shifting or AC coupling to design circuits that can work from a single supply, but that design is not one.